# Fastest way to update multiple records in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to update (upsert) around 5k documents into the Mongodb. I am facing issue that even for 5k it is becoming very slower. I am not sure if it is because i have free Mongo Atlas account. It is taking approx 10min to update all the entries. Below is my code:

```
var bulk = database.collection("job_applications").initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
for (const application of applications) {
    bulk.find({application_id: application['application_id']}).upsert().replaceOne(application);
}
await bulk.execute();
```

I dont think it should take that much time for the 5k entries. Also whatever i researched, i found that initializeUnorderedBulkOp is the fastest way to update multiple entries still its too slow for me.

I am not sure what is the reason here. Is it my free account or it is the code?

Note: The document has around 100 properties. Though i am using `find` first then calling the replace so i don't think it should matter much

Comment: What is `current`?  How many `applications`, 5,000?

Comment: Do you have an index on `application_id`?

Comment: @user20042973 Sorry updated my code. `applications` are 5000

Comment: @ghybs Sorry I dont have that I will try that and get back to you

Comment: I am a bit surprised that this code is working at all. For bulk operation you have to create an array, then fill it with your operations and then execute it. I don't see this in your code. Can you use `updateMany`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit array is needed in case of Bulkwrite correct not for initializeUnorderedBulkOp.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this is supposed to be faster,
also read the complete docs here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/rapid/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/

```
db.collection.bulkWrite(
   [ <operation 1>, <operation 2>, ... ],
   {
      writeConcern : <document>,
      ordered : <boolean>
   }
)
```